# Type mismatch error when fetching API with RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, fetch-api, type-mismatch

I'm trying to fetch API with RxJava by following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VObSnk5jrpc&list=PLRRNzqzbPLd906bPH-xFz9Oy2IcjqVWCH&index=6

But I got an error saying:

Type mismatch.
Required: io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable!
Found: io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.Disposable!

Here is the code:

```
    try{        
       compositeDisposable.add(
            apiService.getMovieDetails(movieId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(
                    {
                        _downloadedMovieDetailsResponse.postValue(it)
                        _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED)
                    },
                    {
                        _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.ERROR)
                        Log.e("MovieDetailsDataSource", it.message!!) //this is where the error is (the it.message)
                    }
                )
        )
    }

    catch (e: Exception){ 
        Log.e("MovieDetailsDataSource",e.message!!) //this is where the error is (the e.message)
    }
```

I tried compositeDisposable.add with capital C, but then it says that I should import something and when I want to import it, it doesn't import it and still show the import error

I don't understand what is the problem.

should I use an old version of RXjava?

is some part of this code deprecated in these new versions of RXjava?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh. finally I solved my problem now.
it was about importing the wrong line.
I deleted the old one from top of the page and replaced it with : import io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.CompositeDisposable
and everything got ok.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to add a couple of Rxjava libraries for io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable.

```
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
```

Then create the object of CompositeDisposable and use it.

```
val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
```

Comment: thanks. you helped me to try and figure it out. i changed that part of code to .subscribeOn(io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers.io()) ,then it got ok. but now i just have one problem. that part that says ".add", it shows error and says that i should import it, but when i click to import, i doesn't do anything. it still shows: io.reactivex.internal.util.BackpressureHelper.add? (multiple choices...) Alt+Enter. it still says: Unresolved reference: add